# One extra `END` in a stored procedure? And it compiles?

Tags: sql-server

I'm decoding a very complex stored procedure and part of that is matching up `BEGIN` `END` pairs.

I have them all matched up except for one problem . . . I have one extra `END` hanging out there at the end of the stored procedure. . . like this:

```
                CLOSE      cursorSelect
          DEALLOCATE cursorSelect  

          /* Select into the record set */
          select *
          from ##tempTable2
          order by selection  

          drop table ##tempTable1
          drop table ##tempTable2  

      commit transaction  

      RETURN

END  --this is the END that seems to have no corresponding `BEGIN`
```

I have counted and there are 62 `BEGIN`s and 63 `END`'s. The crazy thing is if I remove the last `END`, the SP no longer compiles. Is there some other command that requires an `END` to terminate it besides `BEGIN`?

What's going on here?

Comment: Well, it looks like your SQL is messy, that's what's going on! Also, showing just 10 lines of the SQL is not very useful...

Comment: 62 Begins  and 63 Ends..  I would say show your code.  and we can probably help you, but that is probably a huge stored proc.  In addition,  I must say you are probably encorporating too much business logic in the DB.

Comment: Thanks Skliwz, but it's not my SQL. It's legacy SQL and I am trying to reverse engineer it. I can't show it all because it's 14 pages long, and it's got proprietary information in it. Sorry. Hopefully this will be enough to get me an answer!

Comment: @John: It's not my SP. I wish to God I didn't have to reverse engineer it, but I do. It's a mess and I am trying to make a cleaner version, without cursors, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Off the top of my head I would guess you have a `CASE` statement, which terminates with an `END`.
Can you check for that, or post the entire query?

Comment: Indeed I DO have a CASE...THANKS!!! I'm pretty sure that's it! And sorry, it's an SP in a proprietary system and I can't reveal anything. I already had to sanitize the small sample I had above.

Comment: Yup that's it. I can't believe I forgot CASE terminates in an END. Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: +1 Good catch Adam. Didn't even need to see the sproc to boot!